# Possible to directly feed SMILE structures stored in a pandas dataframe into RDKit to calculate molecular fingerprint and similarity?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rdkit

```
ref_Molecule = Chem.MolFromSmiles('CC1=C(C(O)=O)C2=CC(=CC=C2N=C1C3=CC=C(C=C3)C4=CC=CC=C4F)F')

merged_data['Molecule_Tan'] = DataStructs.TanimotoSimilarity(Chem.RDKFingerprint(ref_Brequinar), Chem.RDKFingerprint(Chem.MolFromSmiles(merged_data.SMILES)))
```

I have roughly 1500 SMILES structures stored in my df, merged_data['SMILES'].

I am trying to create a new column of merged_data named 'Molecule_Tan' which I want to populate with the Tanimoto Similarity Index of the data frame smiles verses the reference sequence stored in, `ref_Molecule`.

I tried being efficient by passing the SMILE values directly from the data frame into the nested RDKit functions all on one line using `merged_data.SMILES` or `merged_data['SMILES']`, but when I try to run this I get this error..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filepath", line 69, in <module>
    strasd = Chem.MolFromSmiles(merged_data['SMILES'].astype('object'))

TypeError: No registered converter was able to produce a C++ rvalue of type class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > from this Python object of type Series
```

This error also occurs if I try to give only Chem.MolFromSmiles() the data frame.

Though I'm not 100% clear on it, I *think* the error is related to the pandas data frame trying to give the MolFromSmiles() function a series instead of individual objects.

**What I am trying to figure out is if there is a way that I could manage what I am trying to do within pandas, without writing a loop to iterate over the entire data frame.**

Thank you to anyone who can give me some input on whether what I am trying to do is possible!!!

==============

If it helps, this is roughly what the important parts of my data frame looks like...

```
      Title  ...                                             SMILES
0    236254  ...           Cc1c(-c2ccccc2)n(O)[n+]([O-])c1-c1ccccc1
1     79582  ...                        [O-][n+]1nc2ccccc2c2ccccc21
2     26744  ...                     O=c1cc(-c2ccccc2)oc2ccc(O)cc12
3     38007  ...                     Oc1cc(-c2ccc(Cl)cc2)nc2ccccc12
4    109747  ...                  Cc1cc(O)c2cc(C(=O)c3ccccc3)ccc2n1
..      ...  ...                                                ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, that pandas gives the whole series instead of individual objects, so you have to iterate.

But then the fingerprints can be compared at once with `BulkTanimotoSimilarity()`.

You could try this code:

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit import DataStructs
import pandas as pd

target = Chem.RDKFingerprint(Chem.MolFromSmiles('CC1=C(C(O)=O)C2=CC(=CC=C2N=C1C3=CC=C(C=C3)C4=CC=CC=C4F)F'))

d = {'SMILES': ['Cc1c(-c2ccccc2)n(O)[n+]([O-])c1-c1ccccc1',
                '[O-][n+]1nc2ccccc2c2ccccc21',
                'O=c1cc(-c2ccccc2)oc2ccc(O)cc12',
                'Oc1cc(-c2ccc(Cl)cc2)nc2ccccc12',
                'Cc1cc(O)c2cc(C(=O)c3ccccc3)ccc2n1']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['Tanimoto'] = DataStructs.BulkTanimotoSimilarity(target, [Chem.RDKFingerprint(Chem.MolFromSmiles(s)) for s in df['SMILES']])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                     SMILES  Tanimoto
0  Cc1c(-c2ccccc2)n(O)[n+]([O-])c1-c1ccccc1  0.287625
1               [O-][n+]1nc2ccccc2c2ccccc21  0.178967
2            O=c1cc(-c2ccccc2)oc2ccc(O)cc12  0.273179
3            Oc1cc(-c2ccc(Cl)cc2)nc2ccccc12  0.387127
4         Cc1cc(O)c2cc(C(=O)c3ccccc3)ccc2n1  0.319298
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
I had expected that I might not be able to handle the data frame at once as I had hoped, but it's good to hear a confirmation at least.

Additionally thank you for including that loop! I hadn't realized that you can directly read the output into a new df column, this will definitely help me simplify the process and avoid using extra lists!